# How to Write binary_to_list mysql join query in erlang?

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I have used sql join query in erlang but below code was executed and didnot get answer ,I     have been thinking may be error is occurred in query to list_to_binary conversion 
`Packet = list_to_binary([?MYSQL_QUERY_OP, Query])`this line of execution .

```
ejabberd_odbc:sql_query(
          "192.168.1.14",
          ["select p.id,p.name,p.age,p.phone,i.question from palani p join india i on i.palaniId = p.id;"]).
```

I know I would not send prepare data. please let me know How is send correct format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you write ["a string"] you are building a list containing one single element, the string "a string". The function is expecting a string so you have just to use "select p.id,p.name,p.age,p.phone,i.question from palani p join india i on i.palaniId = p.id;". removing the [ ].

On your example, after reading the documentation, I am not sure that you need the final **';'**, because it is said that semicolon should be used to separate queries in a batch.

In the same manner, I don't find the syntax "select ... from table **p** join ..."

Last, if you want do dynamically build your queries, you can use the io_lib:format/2 and the ++ operator to build it

Comment: dont use ; and create alias by using AS key word  ejabberd_odbc:sql_query(
          "192.168.1.14",
          ["select p.id as id,p.name as name,p.age as age,p.phone as phone,i.question as qu from palani as p join india as i on i.palaniId = p.id"]).